# Preview PDF file on visualforce page

Tags: visualforce, pdf

It is possible to show the first page of an PDF attachment on a visualforce page like a preview?

I have a custom object with some information and a link to a PDF file which is stored in salesforce. I have a list of all these items and I wanna show the first page of the PDF.

EDIT

```
<object
    data="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=0698E0000008oIpQAI"
    width="100%"
    style="height: 100px; border: 1px solid grey;" 
    type="application/pdf"
    />
```

I add this code, but It doesnt work, I just see the border. The file is stored as file and attachment in the custom object.

Comment: Maybe the document you're trying to present is a doc and not pdf? Most ids of pdfs in SF start with `015` and not with `069`..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have used the [object](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_object.asp) tag to display a PDF static resource so I assume this will work for your PDF link:

```
<object
        data="{!linkToPdfFile}"
        width="100%"
        style="height: 500px; border: 1px solid grey;" 
        type="application/pdf"
        />
```

**PS**

Based on the comment thread, I think this is what worked for peXeq:

```
<apex:iframe src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!attachment.id}"/>
```

Comment: I deleted my answer your answer seems more appropriate for this context

Comment: What kind of link is necessary

Comment: @peXeq Just had a Google and found `<apex:iframe src="/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file={!attachment.id}"/>`; give that a quick try. Not to sure what will work fpr an attachment.

Comment: @KeithC, this will try to download the document and present it.

Comment: iframe works fine, for images and pdf documents.